# Проверка решения задачи по программированию онлайн

Tags: алгоритм, архитектура

Перед пользователем стоит задача которую необходимо решить на каком нибудь ЯП. Например:

> Создать 2 переменные, запросить у пользователя ввод двух чисел в эти переменные, посчитать их произведение. Результат вывести на экран.

Проблема заключается в том, что пользователь может решить задачу разными способами. 
Так если это язык JS, то он может декларировать переменные через `let или var или вообще на лету без ключевого слова.` А вывод на экран он может воспроизвести как с помощью `alert(), так и document.write()`

Какие есть варианты проверки задачи пользователя в автоматическом режиме, для примера возьмем JS хотя это не принципиально.
Что то похожее есть на JavaRush.

Comment: Очевидно, просто выполнить код, впихнуть в него ввод и проверить правильность вывода.

Comment: Не менее очевидно, что способы ввода и вывода нужно чётко определить заранее, чтобы не гадать потом про alert и document.write

Comment: @andreymal а если программа не подразумевает вывода на экран?

Comment: Например? . . .

Comment: _программа не подразумевает вывода на экран_ а что тогда делает это программа? если функция ничего не делает, то зачем ее писать? если она что-то делает, значит это можно проверить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение вполне конкретное: вы получаете от пользователя код, исполняете, сверяете выхлоп полученный с выхлопом ожидаемым и сообщаете пользователю насколько он молодец. Для чистоты эксперимента тестовых входных данных подавать необходимо десяток, а то и сотню. Среди них должны встречаться всевозможные предельные случаи.

Есть уже готовые решения для проверки. Например, [ejudge](https://ejudge.ru/wiki/index.php/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_ejudge). В нем вы создаете тур(он создан в контексте олимпиад оп программированию), в туре создаете задачи, для каждой задачи указаны описание, наборы входных данных и соответствующие наборы выходных данных. Умеет проверять кучу разных языков. Может вам хватит этого готового решения, если все же хотите сделать свою систему - можно многое из ejudge подчепрнуть

Comment: Да, то что нужно!